# http.server not serving pages as per example from python.org

Tags: python, httpserver

I'm trying to start a simple dir server on a local network But I am getting this error

> Error response
>
> Error code: 501
>
> Message: Unsupported method ('GET').
>
> Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not
>   support this operation.

This is the example given at https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html If I run it from the command line it works python3 -m http.server. I need to control this server over time so I need to turn it on for a while and turn it off automatically

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer




def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) that you linked to:

> The `HTTPServer` must be given a `RequestHandlerClass` on
>   instantiation, of which this module provides three different variants:
>
> `class http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler(`*`request, client_address, server`*`)`
>
> This class is used to handle the HTTP requests that arrive at the
>   server. **By itself, it cannot respond to any actual HTTP requests; it
>   must be subclassed to handle each request method (e.g. `GET` or
>   `POST`)**. ...

For your case you should use [`http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) instead:

> `class http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(`*`request, client_address, server`*`)`
>
> This class serves files from the current directory and below, directly
>   mapping the directory structure to HTTP requests.